# How to make a dynamic comment box next to \address cluster?

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, boxes, letters, addresses

I'm sure you're aware what \address{blah} is. Well, I'd like to make a boxed comment that's just as high as my address and stretches from the left margin of the document to 3cm to the left of the address:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[standard]{letter}
\usepackage{invoice}
\address{\emph{Invoice from:} \\ My Address \\ My Address \\ My Address}
\signature{Piglet Master}
\date{23. May 2009}
\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{\emph{Invoice to:} \\ My Address \\ My Address \\ My Address}
    \opening{Invoice no. 1}
    My greeting \footnote{I am a man.}
    \begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}
      \ProjectTitle{Example Project}%
      \Fee{Development} {1000.00} {1}
    \end{invoice}
    \closing{Invoice Release Authorization}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal, complete document showing how are you producing your letter.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, see my edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `\address{}` will give original definition of address.  Using `\address[]{}` will give blank invoice box to the left, and using `\address[comment\\comment]{}` will add comment to the invoice box.

```
\documentclass[standard]{letter}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\edef\tmpbs{\the\baselineskip}
\setstackgap{L}{\tmpbs}
\newlength\tmpwd
\newlength\tmpht
\usepackage{invoice}
\fboxrule=1pt

\let\svaddress\address
\renewcommand\address[2][]{% OPTIONAL ARGUMENT AS [~] FOR EMPTY INVOICE BOX
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\svaddress{#2}\else
  \def\theaddress{#2}\invoicenote{#1}\fi}

\def\invoicenote#1{%
  \def\stackalignment{l}
  \setbox0=\hbox{\expandafter\Longstack\expandafter{\theaddress}}
  \tmpwd=\wd0\relax
  \tmpht=\ht0\relax
  \def\y{\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\tmpht}%
    \stackon[\tmpht-\tmpbs]{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth-\tmpwd-3cm\relax}{0pt}}%
    {~\textsf{\strut INVOICE}~~\smash{\Longunderstack{#1}}}}}
  \svaddress{\llap{\y\hspace{3cm}}\expandafter\Longstack\expandafter{\theaddress}}
}

%  ANY OF THESE FORMS WILL WORK:
%\address{\emph{Invoice from:} \\ My Address \\ My Address \\ My Address}
%\address[~]{\emph{Invoice from:} \\ My Address \\ My Address \\ My Address}
\address[Hi, Joe\\ Here is your order]{\emph{Invoice from:} \\ My Address \\ My Address \\ My Address}

\signature{Piglet Master}
\date{23. May 2009}
\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{\emph{Invoice to:} \\ My Address \\ My Address \\ My Address}
    \opening{Invoice no. 1}
    My greeting \footnote{I am a man.}
    \begin{invoice}{Euro}{0}
      \ProjectTitle{Example Project}%
      \Fee{Development} {1000.00} {1}
    \end{invoice}
    \closing{Invoice Release Authorization}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I think I'll delete my answer, since the bug in `invoice.sty` forces a modification of the .sty file itself which should be made by the author and not but users.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I think you describe how it should be altered to avoid the problem.  I would not delete yours yet (unless all the voters agree with you :^).

Comment: I think I'll leave it deleted. I don't like a solution involving modification (even to a copy) of a `.sty` file, and even if it is due to a bug.